# Passing text to console from another app

Tags: c#

I have a few servers (c# console app) and now i'm writting a manager (winform app) to manage them. I'm stuck on server shutdowning. To do this, i need to send a "shutdown" command to each server, it's looks like "/quit" or "/exit".

"Run" method:

```
    public static void RunServer()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo serverInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(serverPath);
        serverInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //serverInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        //serverInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        using (Server = Process.Start(serverInfo))
        {
            if (!MainForm.Instance.InvokeRequired)
            {
                MainForm.Instance.ChangeServerState();
            }
            else
            {
                MainForm.Instance.Invoke(new ChangeButtonState(MainForm.Instance.ChangeServerState));
            }

            Server.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Do not pay attention to "if/else" statements.
This code works fine.
Next i'm trying to close server and `Server.Kill()` is not my way to do this bcs i need to save all server's data.

My "Exit" method:

```
    public static void ExitServer()
    {
        if (!Server.HasExited)
        {
            Server.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"/exit");
            Server.StandardInput.Flush();
            Server.StandardInput.Close();
        }
    }
```

...And... it's doesnt work bcs the standart in/output needs to be redirected(Exception told me that). Okay, uncomment two lines in "Run" method, it's starting but console does not output anything and "Exit" method works fine.
So, my question is, what should i do to return the console output?
Thanks.

Comment: I assume you've tried just `serverInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true` without redirecting output as well?

Comment: Have you tried using OWIN selfhosting.  You can create an web API controller and host  it in you "server" apps, you can then create a simple restful API for controlling them. You might also want to look at topshelf, it makes it easy to turn console apps into windows services. http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: About serverInfo.RedirectStandartOutput = true, i tried set it to false, i doesn't work.

Comment: About OWIN, thanks for replying, will look at him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all for replying. The problem solved by using "InputSimulator" and "SetWindowPos" in user.dll.

```
    private static void SimulateExitInput()
    { 
        InputSimulator iS = new InputSimulator();
        iS.Keyboard.TextEntry(@"/exit");
        iS.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

    private static void ActivateProcess(int PID)
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(PID);
        IntPtr mainWindow = proc.MainWindowHandle;

        IntPtr newPos = new IntPtr(0);  // 0 puts it on top of Z order.   You can do new IntPtr(-1) to force it to a topmost window, instead.
        SetWindowPos(mainWindow, new IntPtr(0), 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
```

Finally "Exit" method looks like:

```
    public static void ExitServer()
    {
        if (Server == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!Server.HasExited)
        {
            ActivateProcess(Server.Id);
            SimulateExitInput();
        }
    }
```